# Information about Embeddings in the Allen Coreference Model

Tags: allennlp, coreference-resolution

I'm an Italian student approaching the NLP world.
First of all I'd like to thank you for the amazing work you've done with the paper " Higher-order Coreference Resolution with Coarse-to-fine Inference".
I am using the model provided by allennlp library and I have two questions for you.

1. in https://demo.allennlp.org/coreference-resolution it is written that the embedding used is SpanBERT. Is this a BERT embedding trained regardless of the coreference task? I mean, could I possibly use this embedding just as a pretrained model on the english language to embed sentences? (e.g. like https://huggingface.co/facebook/bart-base )
2. is it possible to modify the code in order to return, along with the coreference prediction, also the aforementioned embeddings of each sentence?

I really hope you can help me.
Meanwhile I thank you in advance for your great availability.
Sincerely,
Emanuele Gusso

Answer (score 0):

SpanBERT is a version of BERT pre-trained to produce useful embeddings on text spans. SpanBERT itself has nothing to do with coreference resolution. The original paper is https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.10529, and the original source code is https://github.com/facebookresearch/SpanBERT, though you might have an easier time using the huggingface version at https://huggingface.co/SpanBERT.

It is definitely possible to get the embeddings as output, along with the coreference predictions. I recommend cloning https://github.com/allenai/allennlp-models, getting it to run in your environment, and then changing the code until it gives you the output you want.